# Telerik Grid: Handle click event on thick button within custom template opened on edit command

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using a Telerik grid in an ASP.NET MVC view. I am completely new in Telerik.

My Telerik grid is as below:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<MyDTOs.DetalleDTO>()
                        .Name("GridActividadesOferta")
                        .DataKeys(keys =>
                        {
                            keys.Add(d => d.indiceInterno).RouteKey("indiceInterno");
                        })
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(cl => cl.nombreActividad).Title(Inspecciones.lblGridActividad.ToUpper()).ReadOnly(true).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "actividad-column" });
                            columns.Bound(cl => cl.nombreSubActividad).Title(Inspecciones.lblGridSubActividad.ToUpper()).ReadOnly(true);
                            columns.Bound(cl => cl.articuloId).Title(Inspecciones.lblGridArticulo.ToUpper()).ReadOnly(true);
                            columns.Bound(cl => cl.CCAA_Expediente).Title("Expediente".ToUpper()).ReadOnly(false).Width(100);
                            columns.Bound(cl => cl.CCAA_Instalacion).Title("Instalación".ToUpper()).ReadOnly(false).Width(100);
                            columns.Bound(cl => cl.importeArticulo).Title("Importe".ToUpper()).ReadOnly(false).Width(100).Format("{0:c}").ClientFooterTemplate("<#= $.telerik.formatString('Total factura') #>");
                            columns.Bound(cl => cl.importeTasa).Title(Resources.Inspecciones.lblGridImporteTasa.ToUpper()).ReadOnly(false).Aggregate(aggr => aggr.Sum().Count())
                                    .Width(100)
                                    .Format("{0:c}")
                                //.ClientFooterTemplate("<#= $.telerik.formatString('{0:c}'," + Model.totalFactura + ")#>")
                                .ClientFooterTemplate("<#= '<span id=spanTotalFactura>' + $.telerik.formatString('{0:c}'," + Model.totalFactura + ") + '</span>' #>")
                                    .Width(100)
                                    .Format("{0:c}");
                            columns.Command(commands =>
                            {
                                commands.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image);
                                commands.Delete().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image);
                            }).Width(100).Visible(!ViewBag.readOnly);
                        })
                        .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
                        {
                            dataBinding.Ajax()
                                .Select("SelectGridVacias1", "Expedientes", new { ofertaComercialId = @Model.ofertaComercialId })
                                .Update("UpdateGridActividadesRegularizables1", "Expedientes", new { ofertaComercialId = @Model.ofertaComercialId })
                                .Delete("DeleteGridActividadesRegularizables1", "Expedientes", new { ofertaComercialId = @Model.ofertaComercialId })
                                ;
                        })
                        .ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBinding("onDataBindingArticulosGrid").OnDataBound("onDataBoundWrapper").OnEdit("onEditDatosArticulo")
                            .OnRowDataBound("onRowDataBound").OnDelete("onDelete").OnError("onErrorGrid"))
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "center-columns" })
                        .Selectable()
                        .Editable(editing =>
                        {
                            editing
                                .Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
                                .TemplateName("DatosArticuloTemplate1")
                                .InsertRowPosition(GridInsertRowPosition.Top);
                        })
            )
```

As you can see above, I have two commands defined, Edit and Delete. The edit command button has a custom template specified in ".Editable". This template is called "DatosArticuloTemplate1" and it is as follows:

```
<div style="width:800px">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            @Html.Label("nombreArticulo", "Descripcion actual".ToUpper())
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.nombreArticuloFacturacion, new { style = string.Format("width:{0}px; ", 800) })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("instalacionId")
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
            @Html.Label("importeArticulo", "Importe".ToUpper())
            @(Html.Telerik().NumericTextBoxFor(model => model.importeArticulo).EmptyMessage("Importe").DecimalDigits(2).InputHtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:90px;" }))
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            @Html.Label("importeTasa", "Importe de tasa".ToUpper())
            @(Html.Telerik().NumericTextBoxFor(model => model.importeTasa).EmptyMessage("Importe").DecimalDigits(2).InputHtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:90px;" }).Value(0))
        </div>
        <div class="span7">
            @Html.Label("unidades", "Instalación".ToUpper())
            @{Html.RenderAction("DropDownListInstalaciones", "SeleccionarInstalacionButton",
                        new
                        {
                            area = "",
                            clienteId = Model.OfertaComercial == null ? "" : Model.OfertaComercial.clienteId,
                            actividadId = Model.actividadId,
                            subActividadId = Model.subActividadId,
                            sociedadId = Model.OfertaComercial == null ? "" : Model.OfertaComercial.sociedadId,
                            dataBindTo = "instalacionId"
                        });
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This custom template looks like this:

[image]

As you can see at the bottom left corner of the custom template, there are two buttons, one to validate the values introduced (thick button) and another to cancel. These buttons are from Telerik.

Now, I am trying to handle the click event on the thick button. Within the click event i want to validate the value introduced for "IMPORTE" field. If value introduced for this field is 0 then I want to popup a javascript alert modal window. This alert window must notify to the user that a value greater than 0 must be entered for that field. Also, custom template window "DatosArticuloTemplate1" must not be closed until user types in a correct value (value > 0) in the "IMPORTE" field. So how can I do it?

Comment: Are those old wrappers (Html.Telerik versus Html.Kendo)? In the current wrappers you can do this: https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/helper-basics/validation

Comment: Yes, they are old wrappers from a few years ago. They are html.telerik, not the new kendo